# How to get PowerShell to play nice with classes in different files?

Tags: java, powershell

I am a student trying to complete an assignment in Java. I use VS Code to write, but I use PowerShell to compile and run the code to ensure compatibility outside my IDE. On my laptop I can do this fine running PowerShell from the javafiles location, but as soon as I use my main computer PowerShell complains!

```
PS C:\FILE LOCATION> javac *.java
Note: Snake.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
PS C:\FILE LOCATION> java Main.java
Main.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
        Controller kontroll = new Controller();
        ^
  symbol:   class Controller
  location: class Main
Main.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
        Controller kontroll = new Controller();
                                  ^
  symbol:   class Controller
  location: class Main
2 errors
error: compilation failed
```

Here is some of the code:

All of Main.java ->

```
class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Controller kontroll = new Controller();
    }
}
```

Some of Controller.java ->

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class Controller {
    private GUI gui;
    private Model modell;

    Controller() {
        gui = new GUI(this);
        modell = new Model(gui);
        }
    //MORE IRRELEVANT CODE
}
```

I have seen similar issues here, but they have involved a Mains folder that I don't currently have. I only have the files I have made myself, in a flat structure inside the folder I run PowerShell from. I also tried setting classpath directly in PowerShell by using this line:

```
-classpath .;
```

Why would PowerShell complain at home, but run fine on my laptop?
How can I troubleshoot this further?

Comment: Try supplying the classpath as `.`. It can work differently depending on the Java version (and implementation, I suppose). I’d recommend not using the default package in general, but that’s a separate issue.

Comment: What is your directory structure? From the root of your project, where are the `.java` files located?

Comment: To Dave:Bear with me here, I'm a total noob... Where would I supply the classpath? So what I would do to not use the default package is create a new project in VS Code and add all the files to that?

Comment: To Code-Apprentice:
All my files are in a flat structure, in the same folder I start PowerShell.

Comment: @KevinHansen Use `@` before someone's user name to ping them directly.

Comment: "Where should I supply the classpath?" There are several ways to do this. I suggest googling "java set classpath" to get started.

Comment: As for defining your own packages, I think you shouldn't worry about it here because you will still need to solve the same problems. When you get there, you can read about packages and how to use them.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thank you for your help. Setting classpath had no other effect.

Comment: *error: compilation failed* That doesn't make sense. Your last command was to *run* your code (`java`) which would not produce that error message. Please post the proper contents of your console

Comment: @g00se The only thing I have removed from the console output is the location. It has no relevance, as I am executing from the location of my files, and I don't want to broadcast my folder names.

Comment: I'm unconvinced. Naturally I was aware of your privacy issue and the steps you took to address it. Anyway, let me say that `javac *.java` will often fail. You need to compile in the correct order of dependence when that happens

Comment: @g00se Be that as it may, I don't know what I can do to convince you otherwise. Thank you for the tip about compiling. I will have to look into that further, as I don't know what order is proper.

Comment: If you place the files somewhere, I can take a look

Comment: @g00se That is very kind of you, but it finally started working somehow. I suspect OneDrive, as I've had other issues with it as well.

Comment: Yes, OneDrive sucks. Certainly don't put code into directories that have any linking going on in them.

Answer (score 0):

The issue resolved itself somehow. I suspect OneDrive, but I have no idea what made it happen.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).